# Joining 2 consecutive lines starts with digits in text file

Tags: python

I have a text file as below and need to join consecutive lines started with Digits and lines not containing 'not eligible' into a csv file

Expected output

```
109797295 3503 2 1
123012179 3417 4 1
123012179 3417 3 1
```

Text File:

```
Date Printed 09/21/22
Batch Number 1481499

109797295 Xie                           Wei Yan                       eligible 
3503  2   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics
WARNING Name Mismatch: Xie Weiyan

120106533 Cheesbrough                   Joanne                        not eligible 
3507  4   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics (Specialised Swim and Water Safety Teacher)
WARNING Name Mismatch: Cheesbrough Joanne Mary

123012179 Wood                          James Michael                 eligible 
3417  4   1   New Zealand Certificate in Entertainment and Event Technology


123012179 Wood                          James Michael                 eligible 
3417  3   1   New Zealand Certificate in Entertainment and Event Technology




managed to write lines with digit, but I dont know to exclude lines with 'not eligible' and write into csv 
with open('qualstatusall.txt') as r:
    for line in r:
        if line and line[0].isdigit():  # no need to compare against True 
           print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Add another `if` condition as `if line and line[0].isdigit() and "not eligible" not in line`

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I need to exclude the next line after line with 'not eligible'

Comment: And also how get them into a csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach

- Block starts when we detect eligible on a line (not "not eligible)
- Get numbers from the line and following line
- Find numbers using regex

**Code**

```
import re

def main(input_file, output_file):
    
    # Helper function to get numbers from blocks
    def get_numbers(filenm):
        '''
            Gets numbers from eligible and next line in file

            When line with elgible is detected (without not elgible)
                Gets numbers from line and following line
        '''           
        with open(filenm) as fin:
            result = []
            on_line = 0
            current = []
            for line in fin:
                line = line.rstrip()

                if 'eligible' in line and not 'not eligible' in line:
                    on_line = 1                # starting block
                elif on_line == 1:
                    on_line = 2                # second line of block
                else:
                    on_line = 0                # no longer in first or second line of block, so add current numbers if any
                    if current:
                        result.append(' '.join(current))
                        current = []

                if 1 <= on_line <= 2:          # get numbers if on first or second line
                    current.extend(re.findall(r'\d+', line))

        if current:
            result.append(' '.join(current))
            current = []
        return result

    # Write desired numbers to output file
    with open(output_file, 'w') as fout:
        for result in get_numbers(input_file):
            fout.write(result + '\n')
```

**Test**

```
main('test.txt', 'results.txt')
```

File: results.txt

```
109797295 3503 2 1
123012179 3417 4 1
123012179 3417 3 1
123136648 3565 1
126482068 3503 2 1
126924914 3503 2 1
127984422 3503 1 1
129097194 2570 1
131767876 3499 1 1
132117685 3503 2 1
132507935 3503 2 1
133137183 2570 1
133825876 3503 1 1
133831632 3503 2 1
136030741 3503 2 1
161587948 3503 2 1
161695000 3503 2 1
161811609 3503 1 1
165396357 3503 1 1
```

File: test.txt (note: "Codie Lee" block has only three numbers vs. four for all the other blocks)

```
New Zealand Qualification Authority
Validation of Qualifications for Skills Active Aotearoa Limited
Date Printed 09/21/22
Batch Number 1481499

109797295 Xie                           Wei Yan                       eligible 
3503  2   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics
WARNING Name Mismatch: Xie Weiyan

120106533 Cheesbrough                   Joanne                        not eligible 
3507  4   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics (Specialised Swim and Water Safety Teacher)
WARNING Name Mismatch: Cheesbrough Joanne Mary

123012179 Wood                          James Michael                 eligible 
3417  4   1   New Zealand Certificate in Entertainment and Event Technology


123012179 Wood                          James Michael                 eligible 
3417  3   1   New Zealand Certificate in Entertainment and Event Technology


123136648 Christensen                   Codie Lee                     eligible 
3565      1   New Zealand Certificate in Freestyle Group Exercise


126482068 Creamer                       Hannah Marie                  eligible 
3503  2   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics


126924914 Wallace                       Claudia Mae                   eligible 
3503  2   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics


127984422 Braden                        Shay Lee                      eligible 
3503  1   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics


129097194 Holloway                      James John                    eligible 
2570      1   New Zealand Certificate in Outdoor Experiences
WARNING Name Mismatch: Holloway James

131767876 Balloch                       Paige Louise                  eligible 
3499  1   1   New Zealand Certificate in Snowsport Equipment


132117685 Haydon                        Rose Francis                  eligible 
3503  2   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics
WARNING Name Mismatch: Haydon Rose Frances Sylvia

132507935 Martin                        Ashleigh Kay Maree            eligible 
3503  2   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics
WARNING Name Mismatch: Martin Ashleigh Kay-Marie

133137183 Hughes                        Shea Daniel                   eligible 
2570      1   New Zealand Certificate in Outdoor Experiences


133825876 Stanford                      Jessica Charlotte             eligible 
3503  1   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics


133831632 Swart                         Wendy                         eligible 
3503  2   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics


136030741 Proctor                       Jessica Claire                eligible 
3503  2   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics


161587948 Coyle                         Janice                        eligible 
3503  2   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics


161695000 Newman                        Rachael                       eligible 
3503  2   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics
WARNING Name Mismatch: Newman Rachael Renee

161811609 Colston                       Adam Matthew                  eligible 
3503  1   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics


165396357 Adeane                        Andrew                        eligible 
3503  1   1   New Zealand Certificate in Aquatics
WARNING Name Mismatch: Adeane Andrew Robert
```

Comment: `if 'eligible' in block.split('\n')[0]:` isn't it matches with `not eligible` lines?

Comment: @Ramesh thanks for noticing.  Made correction.

Comment: Thanks Darryl and Ramesh. Sorry but I get nothing in result file when I run this

Comment: @JayWeera 1) Is the data in file "test.txt" and 2) is the content of the data file what you posted in your question?

Comment: Darryl, sorry I put a wrong file name. Now I can see results, but the result has numbers coming from 'not eligible' block as well. and also some number blocks are not appending from some 'eligible' blocks as well. The file has 16 eligible blocks but result file has only 7 blocks including 'not eligible'

Comment: I found the issue here in the input txt file - some blocks are separated by one blank line and others are 2 blank lines. Also how can I use 'join' function to append results in columns like csv

Comment: @JayWeera can you provide a link to your file (i.e. by placing it in an online repository so I can access it)?

Comment: https://github.com/jayweera/SkillsActive/upload/master

Comment: File name: qualstatusall.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249311/discussion-between-darrylg-and-jay-weera).

Comment: Thanks Darryl, I ran but I get blank file as output